# RandomAccessFile reading ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, iso-8859-1, randomaccessfile

I have a RandomAccessFile reading from a file that contains ISO-8859-1 characters *(åäö)*. But when use seek() and readLine() on the file I get **aagÃ¥rd** instead of **aagård**. Any clue why this is?

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine doesn't support UTF format as in javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine()

> Reads the next line of text from this file. This method successively
>   reads bytes from the file, starting at the current file pointer, until
>   it reaches a line terminator or the end of the file. Each byte is
>   converted into a character by taking the byte's value for the lower
>   eight bits of the character and setting the high eight bits of the
>   character to zero. This method does not, therefore, support the full
>   Unicode character set.

Try `ReadUTF()` instead:

> Reads in a string from this file. The string has been encoded using a
>   modified UTF-8 format.